# Sending mouse and keyboard input to a unity3d game (Rust)

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, input, keyboard, mouse

I would like a python option but that doesn't seem likely, I looked into c++ but I'm not intimately familiar and the methods I tried were not working. I need to be able to move the mouse(which I have been able to do) inside the game (which never works), and to press and or hold keys, AutoHotKey doesn't work for moving the mouse inside of popup dialogs only for controlling recoil and such. I have permission from the admin, I admin on one of his other servers, I'm not looking to release hacks for the game, its just a project I dabbled with for a while and would like to see out.

Does anyone have experience with this or ideas as to how I can simulate input from mouse or keyboard?

Comment: Maybe AutoIT, but AHT is made based on AutoIT

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I did try auto-it, It wasn't working well for the input and I need the ability to use loops as well as color detection for the project.

Answer (score 0):

i have expeience in ahk and game bot making
https://www.youtube.com/user/FloowSnaake/videos